# python add numbers in front of lines and export it to a new file

Tags: python-3.x

i have a file(`A.txt`) that it has a series of lines. i would like to read file(A) and create a new file(`B`) and add a number and a semicolon at the beginning and a space before the text of each line. at the moment i have:

```
with open('A.txt','r+') as f:
for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), start=1):
    print('{:4d}: {}'.format(index, line.rstrip()))
```

the above code takes the file(`A`) and adds the number in the format i want. The problem is that i do not know how to leave file(`A.txt`), just read the contents of `A.txt`, as it is and make all changes to file(`B.txt`).
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

Open file B in write-mode, `open("B.txt", "w")`, then instead of calling `print`, call write on the new file descriptor.

```
with open("A.txt", "r") as a, open("B.txt", "w") as b:
    b.write(...)
```

Your program would look like:

```
with open("A.txt", "r") as a, open("B.txt", "w") as b:
    index = 1
    for line in a:
        b.write("{:4d}: {}\n".format(index, line.rstrip()))
        index += 1
```

Comment: OK, it seems that it worked, but it putted all the different lines of A.txt, in a single line of B.txt. How do i fix that?

Comment: @john I forgot to add newline in the example, check the edited answer.